# how to count all rows are approved in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have this line data, where it also shows the status: `approved, in progress, not yet started`.
I need to count how many lines are ALL APROVED based on the line colors.

the data is similar to this:

```
line    color       status
1       red      not yet started
2       red       approved
3       green     approved
4       green     approved
5       green     approved
```

the query should show that there is only color (which is green) that all the status are approved, because red still have the "not yet started" status.

I have tried

```
select color count(line) from table 1 where status = 'approved' group by color
```

it still give me 2 colors are approved, while I expect there would only one.

How should I fix my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can count only approved and count all, then compare them with `HAVING` part of SQL.

Comment: Add `HAVING !SUM(status != 'approved')` - this checks that none row has a status other than 'approved'.

Comment: Or just find ones 'not approved' and then not select those

Comment: There is 2 colors approved in you structure => 1 red, 3 greens, so, the is no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select color, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by color
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'approved'
```

The `having` clause ensures that there is only one distinct value in the group, whose value is `'approved'`.

In MySQ, you could also phrase the `having` clause like so:

```
having max(status <> 'approved') = 0
```

Or simply:

```
having not max(status <> 'approved')
```

Comment: `having not max(status <> 'approved')` this is smart ! this is only valid in MySQL?

Comment: @Cid: indeed, this is not standard SQL... Other databases might have shortcuts as well. Eg in Postgres, we could use boolean aggregation: `having bool_and(status = 'approved')`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the count of colors that are all approved, you can use this method:

```
select (count(distinct color) -
        count(distinct case when status <> 'approved' then color end)
       )
from t;
```

This counts the number of colors in your table and then subtracts the number of colors that have a non-"approved" status.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach (get colors where rows count equal approved rows count):

```
select color 
from tbl 
group by color
having count(*) = count(case when status = 'approved' then status end);
```

Here the [fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1f1a99cc41a8c0bc2262882965ce6938&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)